# How to rotate object on axis (planet)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, axis

Ok Im not sure whether this has been addressed specifically but I have some planet orbit rings that I need to rotate ON the axis, meaning they stay at an angle but rotate -

so far Ive parented the ring to an empty and am just rotating the empty which results in this (NOT good):

1. [image]
2. [image]

The tilt should always be more/less like #1 - how can I do this?

Comment: I think to achieve this, you need to change the `transformation orientation` from `global` to `local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this particular rotation, you need to change the `transformation orientation` from `global` to `local` [image: E.g.]

Then if you press <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate and then <kbd>Z</kbd> twice, you will rotate the object on its local Z-axis. **You don't have to have changed the transformation orientation to achieve this, it just help visualise the axis you're going to use**

[image: Final]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry - did that but still waving around/ not going locally

Comment: Try rotating it on other local axis apart from the Z